# Suggestion: Make print tag a synonym of printing

Tags: support, tags

There are 29 questions tagged [`print`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print) (with no tag wiki) and 72 tagged [`printing`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printing) (with a tag wiki).

Should `print` tags redirect to `printing`?

Comment: I completely agree! They are the same and should be merged/made synonyms.

Comment: Thank you: I'll take care of it.  We have a mechanism for suggesting tag synonyms, though, partly to keep our meta site from become cluttered by innumerable question threads like this one.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks. I did see the title of that question but didn't bother opening it as it sounds irrelevant. Perhaps it should be renamed to "Add you tag suggestions here!!!".

Comment: Good idea, Hugo: I edited the title to make that thread a little more accessible.